# Reset password of the embedded webserver on a hp color cm4730 mfp?

Tags: password-recovery

There's an internal webserver on this hp color cm4730 mfp which we set to a random password which nobody wrote down... how do we reset it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold <kbd>6</kbd> on bootup, press <kbd>3</kbd>, press <kbd>6</kbd>.

Comment: I don't know how many times you have to press <kbd>3</kbd>

Comment: Remembered how it was.

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold <kbd>9</kbd> during bootup until the LEDs light up and stay on. Then press <kbd>3</kbd>, then press <kbd>start</kbd>, then <kbd>3</kbd> once or twice more until `NVRAM INIT` appears. If you press <kbd>3</kbd> too many times, keep pressing <kbd>3</kbd> and it will loop back around to `NVRAM INIT`. Finally, press <kbd>6</kbd>.

Let the printer boot up. If everything worked, when you view the web interface for the printer, you won't see a link to log in, because you're already logged in as admin. Promptly change the admin password.